# loading sqlsrv driver in php.ini

Tags: sql, sql-server, configuration, php

i got php5.4.4
and i've downloaded sqlsrv driver for working with microsoft SQL
putted the dll in the ext folder of php and in the php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Microsoft SQL Server ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems=-1
sqlsrv.LogSeverity=-1
sqlsev.WarningsReturnAsErrors=0
```

but when loading

> phpinfo()

the extension doesn't show up .

am i doing something wrong here?!

thanks in advance.

Comment: yep sorry. changed it to sqlsrv* but still . :/

Comment: Do you use IIS as your web server?

Answer (score 0):

extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll should be in [ExtensionList] section, the rest of the parameters should be in [sqlsrv]:

```
(...)

[ExtensionList]
(...)
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll

(...)

[sqlsrv]
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems=-1
sqlsrv.LogSeverity=-1
sqlsev.WarningsReturnAsErrors=0

(...)
```

Comment: [ExtensionList] doesn't exist in php.ini (php 8.1) and you should only use filename without extension (".dll").

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set extension to the filename without extension these days (php 8.1):

```
extension=php_sqlsrv
```

The other 3 values are only needed if you don't want the defaults.

Most important is the extension_dir setting. It is recommended to use absolute path:

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\php\ext"
```